# How to calculate multiple columns from multiple columns in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns, calculated-columns

I am trying to calculate multiple colums from multiple columns in a pandas dataframe using a function.
The function takes three arguments -a-, -b-, and -c- and and returns three calculated values -sum-, -prod- and -quot-. In my pandas data frame I have three coumns -a-, -b- and and -c- from which I want to calculate the columns -sum-, -prod- and -quot-.

The mapping that I do works only when I have exactly three rows. I do not know what is going wrong, although I expect that it has to do something with selecting the correct axis. Could someone explain what is happening and how I can calculate the values that I would like to have.
Below are the situations that I have tested.

**INITIAL VALUES**

```
def sum_prod_quot(a,b,c):
    sum  = a + b + c
    prod = a * b * c
    quot = a / b / c
    return (sum, prod, quot)

df = pd.DataFrame({ 'a': [20, 100, 18],
                    'b': [ 5,  10,  3],
                    'c': [ 2,  10,  6],
                    'd': [ 1,   2,  3]
                 })

df
    a   b   c  d
0   20   5   2  1
1  100  10  10  2
2   18   3   6  3
```

**CALCULATION STEPS**

**Using exactly three rows**

When I calculate three columns from this dataframe and using the function function I get:

```
df['sum'], df['prod'], df['quot'] = \
        list( map(sum_prod_quot, df['a'], df['b'], df['c']))

df
     a   b   c  d    sum     prod   quot
0   20   5   2  1   27.0    120.0   27.0
1  100  10  10  2  200.0  10000.0  324.0
2   18   3   6  3    2.0      1.0    1.0
```

This is exactly the result that I want to have: The sum-column has the sum of the elements in the columns a,b,c; the prod-column has the product of the elements in the columns a,b,c and the quot-column has the quotients of the elements in the columns a,b,c.

**Using more than three rows**

When I expand the dataframe with one row, I get an error!

The data frame is defined as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'a': [20, 100, 18, 40],
                    'b': [ 5,  10,  3, 10],
                    'c': [ 2,  10,  6,  4],
                    'd': [ 1,   2,  3,  4]
                 })
df
     a   b   c  d
0   20   5   2  1
1  100  10  10  2
2   18   3   6  3
3   40  10   4  4
```

The call is

```
df['sum'], df['prod'], df['quot'] = \
        list( map(sum_prod_quot, df['a'], df['b'], df['c']))
```

The result is

```
...
    list( map(sum_prod_quot, df['a'], df['b'], df['c']))
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

while I would expect an extra row:

```
df
     a   b   c  d    sum     prod   quot
0   20   5   2  1   27.0    120.0   27.0
1  100  10  10  2  200.0  10000.0  324.0
2   18   3   6  3    2.0      1.0    1.0
3   40  10   4  4   54.0   1600.0    1.0
```

**Using less than three rows**

When I reduce tthe dataframe with one row I get also an error.
The dataframe is defined as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'a': [20, 100],
                    'b': [ 5,  10],
                    'c': [ 2,  10],
                    'd': [ 1,   2]
                 })
df
     a   b   c  d
0   20   5   2  1
1  100  10  10  2
```

The call is

```
df['sum'], df['prod'], df['quot'] = \
        list( map(sum_prod_quot, df['a'], df['b'], df['c']))
```

The result is

```
...
    list( map(sum_prod_quot, df['a'], df['b'], df['c']))
ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
```

while I would expect a row less:

```
df
     a   b   c  d    sum     prod   quot
0   20   5   2  1   27.0    120.0   27.0
1  100  10  10  2  200.0  10000.0  324.0
```

**QUESTIONS**

The questions I have:

1)  Why do I get these errors?

2)  How do I have to modify the call such that I get the desired data frame?

**NOTE**

In [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28398345/how-to-create-multiple-columns-from-multiple-columns-in-a-pandas-data-frame) a similar question is asked, but the given answer did not work for me.

Comment: Are you sure your answer is correct? Can you check product column as well?

Comment: There is an easier way to do this `df['sum'] = df['a'] + df['b'] + df['c']` and the same for the other operations. Unless this is just an example for the error

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The above is an example to show the error. The original function is a function in another module. The solution provided by open-source does the trick.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer doesn't seem correct for `3` rows as well. Can you check other values except `first row and first column`. Looking at the results, product of `20*5*2` is **NOT** `120`, it's `200` and is placed below in `sum` column. You need to form list in correct way before assigning to new columns. You can try use following to set the new columns:

```
df['sum'], df['prod'], df['quot'] = zip(*map(sum_prod_quot, df['a'], df['b'], df['c']))
```

For details follow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19343/5916727)

Comment: This is exactly the line I was looking for. Thanks. It also works with the original function (which is placed in another module) where I need to calculate polar coordinates from rectangular coordinates.

Comment: @PeterDev Great! if you would like you can accept the answer. `Happy Coding`.

Comment: What does the unzipping and rezipping in zip(*map(...)) do? Seems like redundant work.

Answer (score 1):

The `apply()` method can be used for this problem, when providing the `result_type` argument:

```py
df[["sum", "prod", "quot"]] = df.apply(
    lambda row: sum_prod_quot(row["a"], row["b"], row["c"]),
    axis=1,
    result_type="expand",
)
```

alternatively (faster for larger dataframes) use `apply()` only on a selection of the dataframe and unpacking the values of `row`

```py
df[["sum", "prod", "quot"]] = df[["a", "b", "c"]].apply(
    lambda row: sum_prod_quot(*row),
    axis=1,
    result_type="expand",
)
```

In both cases, the `return` value of `sum_prod_quot()` is added as new columns to `df`.

Explanation:

- `apply()` with `axis=1` applies the function (first argument) to each row separately.
- Use of `lambda` takes care that passing of `row` matches the function's signature (`sum_prod_quot()` requires 3 arguments).
- `result_type="expand"` turns the list-like return value of `sum_prod_quot()` into columns.
- We can then directly assign the data of these now columns to the (new) `"sum"`, `"prod"`, and `"quot"` columns of `df` (`df[["sum", "prod", "quot"]]`).

For further info see [pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).